# how to use MAX in clicpilot

Tags: javascript, html, sql

```
    <table class="cp-query content" cp-entity-name="WindPower" cp-action-name="QueryWindPowerTotal" cp-field="['MAX PTime MAXTime', 'InvRefe1.WindDynamoId P','InvRefe1.DynamoType']">
                <tr >
                    <td>{{=it.P||'&nbsp;'}}</td>
                    <td>{{=(it.InvRefe1?(it.InvRefe1.DynamoType||'&nbsp;'):'&nbsp;')}}</td>
                    <td>{{=it.Power||'&nbsp;'}}</td>
                    <td>{{=it.MAXTime||'&nbsp;'}}</td>
                </tr>
    </table>
```

Once I add "power" in cp-field, the record won't aggregation by "time":.But I can't get "power" record if I don't add it.

First datatable:

WINDPOWERID PTIME   POWER

Second datatable:

WINDDYNAMOID    DYNAMOTYPE

Third:

WINDDYNAMOID WINDPOWERID

Comment: I found that clicpilt will use "group by " for all columns ... so I can't add additional columns in MAX table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that clicpilot will group all the columns when use MAX. I use cp-order-field="['PTime']" cp-order-type="DESC" , and hide the other rows to solve the problem temporarily.